# Submitting image directly through AJAX?

Tags: ajax, forms, image-upload, form-submit

After looking around at some stuff, I've found that you can submit a form to a frame using the "target" attribute.

That works for me, except, it submits the WHOLE form.

I have a form. It's all submitted to a PHP file with AJAX POST.

I want to include an image upload in this form.

Is there any way to directly upload the image THROUGH AJAX to the same PHP file, or do I have to put a form within a form (because I think that that's rather sloppy).

Thanks a bunch!

NO jQuery. Straightforward DOM, please.

Comment: Yes but no support for older browsers.

Comment: That's fine. What's the cuttoff? IE8?

Comment: For IE its 10, for the others I don't really know, http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2

Comment: That's a pretty bad cut off...I guess I could put a form within a form, but..Is it "legal" according to the HTML5 syntax?

Comment: Nope, the parser will probably chop the first one when the second one starts.

Comment: Any other workarounds?